# Carthage PO doesn't work after update - "error: expression failed to parse: error: stat cache file, couldn't IRGen expression"

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

After updating a project and re-building/bootstrapping the dependencies for the new deployment target (13.0->14.0) I can't use PO in the xCode console anymore. I'm installing dependencies with

```
carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --verbose --use-xcframeworks --no-use-binaries
```

When printing something I get the following output:

```
(lldb) po mainStack
error: expression failed to parse:
error: stat cache file '/Users/steven/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/14.3_14E222b/PhoneNumberKit/3.5.10/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator16.4-20E238-.sdkstatcache' not found
error: stat cache file '/Users/steven/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/14.3_14E222b/PhoneNumberKit/3.5.10/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator16.4-20E238-.sdkstatcache' not found

error: couldn't IRGen expression. Please check the above error messages for possible root causes.
error: expression failed to parse:
error: stat cache file '/Users/steven/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/14.3_14E222b/PhoneNumberKit/3.5.10/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator16.4-20E238-.sdkstatcache' not found
error: stat cache file '/Users/steven/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/14.3_14E222b/PhoneNumberKit/3.5.10/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator16.4-20E238-.sdkstatcache' not found

error: couldn't IRGen expression. Please check the above error messages for possible root causes.
error: expression failed to parse:
error: stat cache file '/Users/steven/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/14.3_14E222b/PhoneNumberKit/3.5.10/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator16.4-20E238-.sdkstatcache' not found
error: stat cache file '/Users/steven/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/14.3_14E222b/PhoneNumberKit/3.5.10/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator16.4-20E238-.sdkstatcache' not found

error: couldn't IRGen expression. Please check the above error messages for possible root causes.
```

I tried replacing the PhoneNumberKit dependency with the swift package manager one but then the errors just shows the next framework and so on.
The frameworks are pushed to gitLFS but when other developers try to print, they get the same error with the same /Users/steven/ path how is that possible?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you manager to solve this issue at all? I'm facing a similar one